# DuplicateDefinitionError: a type with name is already registered

Tags: polymer, microsoft-edge

http://invisu.me/onepager?k=CaUGMFtxl8hqHNtN2cObYA_c_c

I've got this web page that loads fine in Chrome, and even in IE11, but the Edge browser shows a blank page and eventually the tab's title becomes "Not responding...", while the Edge process shows it's doing some work.

When viewing the F12 console, after waiting for a few minutes..., it starts spitting endless number of DuplicateDefinitionErrors. Actually a bunch of these per each type being used by the page.

This is how it looks like on Win10 preview Edge browser (from VirtualBox):
[image: edge console screenshot]

Using Polymer 1.0.

Please help resolve this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Found a commit that fixed it:

https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/commit/40d02d6bd4e94650b204beb7dd5cf0ff80ca695e